# In Karate 1.4.0, it is not possible to conceal sensitive form-data, request headers, or response JSONPath expressions in Karate HTML Report and logs

Tags: automation, karate, karate-call-single

In Karate 1.4.0, there is no built-in functionality to securely mask or hide sensitive information such as form-data, request headers, or response JSONPath expressions, which means that these elements cannot be effectively protected or obscured in this version of the software.

I have tried https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#log-masking. But, not success. Please guide.

Comment: it is supposed to work. the best guide is in the documentation and other teams seem to be doing fine. your question does not meet stack overflow guidelines, consider revising it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: After reading the documentation again, I was able to mask the headers and response successfully.

Comment: Have we made any changes with the HTML reporting, where previously (in 1.4.0) we were able to see the API request and response details when expanding the HTTP method link in the report. Now, after upgrading it to 1.4.1 can't see it anymore. Can we configure this feature? Is it disabled by default?

Comment: no changes. if you have some library conflicts you have to sort it out, or help us replicate by following this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - also see if the "fat jar" option helps: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-examples/blob/main/database/README.md#using-the-shaded-jar